# two same name input field insert into database

Tags: php, html, mysql

i got this input form with php

```
<?php
$name = $d['namescenario'];

if ($name == "Q1"){

  echo"<div class='form-group'>
    <select class='form-control' id='scenario' name='scenario'>
      <option>Q1 First</option>
      <option>Q1 Second</option>
      <option>Q1 Third</option>
      <option>Q1 Fourth</option>
    </select>
  </div>";

}

else if ($namascen == "Q2") {

  echo"<div class='form-group'>
    <select class='form-control' id='scenario' name='scenario'>
      <option>Q2 First</option>
      <option>Q2 Second</option>
      <option>Q2 Third</option>
      <option>Q2 Fourth</option>
    </select>
  </div>";

}

else if ($namascen == "Q3") {

  echo"<div class='form-group'>
    <select class='form-control' id='scenario' name='scenario'>
      <option>Q3 First</option>
      <option>Q3 Second</option>
      <option>Q3 Third</option>
      <option>Q3 Fourth</option>
    </select>
  </div>";

}

else if ($namascen == "Q4") {

  echo"<div class='form-group'>
    <select class='form-control' id='scenario' name='scenario'>
      <option>Q3 First</option>
      <option>Q3 Second</option>
      <option>Q3 Third</option>
      <option>Q3 Fourth</option>
    </select>
  </div>";

}

}

?>
```

is it possible to get form like that?

and this is my query

```
$namescenario= $_POST['scenario'];

  $upds=$db->query("UPDATE scenario SET scenario='$keterangan' WHERE noid='$noid' AND project='$project' AND nama_scen='$nama_scen'");
```

Comment: I see no problem at all with the flows. But you could be way more efficient with the code. You might want to add the `value` attribute to your `options`. What is exactly the problem again?

Comment: what's the issue here?please clarify your question. i saw  2 issues:-
 1.values are not given to select options 2.query is wide open to _`SQL INJECTION`_

Comment: Yes, It is possible. But I noticed that there is an extra close brace in your code